# Java Spring and Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a simple web app using Java Spring and deploy it to Google App Engine, but I can't find a clear guide for setting up the project.
I'm using Eclipse with the Goole plugin ("New web application project...").
I created all the controllers and I have a configuration file like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I don't want a web.xml file.
How can I create the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the "[Google App Engine For Java - Spring Basic set up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEnzaTytg3Q)" on how to create your Java Spring project and how to properly set up the Spring configurations.